# How to not display the result of compare, using Apache Velocity?

Tags: java, tomcat, velocity

I'm using Apache Velocity to personalize e-mails (via HTML and CSS, in which I put some Java variables)

Here is my problem :

I have a String List, named $listString :

```
#set($listString = [])
```

In this List, I put some stuff :

```
$listString.add("aaa");
$listString.add("bbb");
```

Now, I want to know if this List contains or not "bbb" :

```
#if (($listString.contains("bbb")) == true)
    Yeah ! It contains bbb !
#end
```

So the sentence "*Yeah ! It contains bbb*" should appears ... And it's appears ...
But in the content of the e-mail, there is "***true;***" in the begining of the sentence ...

```
 true; Yeah ! It contains bbb !
```

The result is the same with this compare :

```
#if ($listString.contains("bbb"))
    Yeah ! It contains bbb !
#end
```

How to not display the result of this compare, which is using the "contains()" method ?

How to not display the "true;" ?

Thank you !

Comment: Thank you for your response, but yes, the result is the same, with or without the "== true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to redirect the result of the add method to another variable like:

```
  #set ( $success = $listString.add("aaa") )
  #set ( $success = $listString.add("bbb") )

  #set ($res = $listString.contains("bbb"))

  #if ( $res == true)
      Yeah ! It contains bbb !
   #end
```